# MariaDB / CodeIgniter / PHPColors

Tags: php, mariadb, codeigniter-3

Can somebody help me with this error.

The PHP below

```
    public function color_sql($filter)
{
    $this->db->select('*, sum(count) AS color_sum');
    $this->db->from('wallpapers_colors');
    $this->db->where('saturation BETWEEN ' . (($filter['saturation'][0]) / 100) . ' AND ' . (($filter['saturation'][1]) / 100));
    $this->db->where('lightness BETWEEN ' . (($filter['lightness'][0]) / 100) . ' AND ' . (($filter['lightness'][1]) / 100));
    $this->db->where('hue BETWEEN ' . ($filter['hue'][0]) . ' AND ' . ($filter['hue'][1]));
    $this->db->group_by('wallpaper_seq_id');
    return $this->sql();
}
```

**returns the below error**

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN0 AND 0.4 AND `lightness` BETWEEN 0.08 AND 0.48 AND `hue` BETWEEN0 AND 20' at line 4

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM ((SELECT *, sum(count) AS color_sum FROM `WS_wallpapers_colors` WHERE `saturation` BETWEEN0 AND 0.4 AND `lightness` BETWEEN 0.08 AND 0.48 AND `hue` BETWEEN0 AND 20 GROUP BY `wallpaper_seq_id`) wc) JOIN `WS_wallpapers` `w` ON `w`.`wallpaper_seq_id` = `wc`.`wallpaper_seq_id` LEFT JOIN (SELECT `t2`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_slug order by c1.lvl desc SEPARATOR '/') AS cFullSlug, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name order by c1.lvl desc SEPARATOR '|') AS cFullName FROM `WS_closures` `c1` LEFT JOIN `WS_category` `c` ON `c`.`category_seq_id` = `c1`.`ancestor` LEFT JOIN `WS_category` `t2` ON `t2`.`category_seq_id` = `c1`.`descendant` GROUP BY `c1`.`descendant`) as c ON `c`.`category_seq_id` = `w`.`category_seq_id` WHERE `w`.`wallpaper_status` = 1 AND `w`.`wallpaper_approved` = 1

Filename: core/WS_Model.php

Line Number: 76
```

**core/WS_Model.php**

```
public function count() {
    $this->eachDay_newCache();
    $this->ShutDownCache();
    $return = $this->db->count_all_results(); // this is line 76 from WS_Model.php
    $this->turnOnCache();
    return $return;
}
```

Anyone have any solution how to solve this error?
(As you can see there is a space in the PHP code after the "BETWEEN" word and I don't know why MariaDB seen without a space.)

*Thank you!*

Comment: `BETWEEN0`?  There needs to be a space after `BETWEEN`.  Since you seem to have a space in the code provided, it is puzzling.

Comment: What is your sql() method in your model?

Answer (score 0):

Your Error message ( in part ) says

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM
```

and in your SQL it says

```
$this->db->select('*, sum(count) AS color_sum');
```

They are two different things

So what is the actual code you have at line 76 in core/WS_Model.php because the error code is not coming from the SQL you have shown us.

Comment: Tim thanks for trying to help me.

   `public function count()
    {
        $this->eachDay_newCache();
        $this->ShutDownCache();
        $return = $this->db->count_all_results(); // this is line 76 from WS_Model.php
        $this->turnOnCache();
        return $return;
    }
   `

Comment: That doesn't really help any... What you have to go looking for, is where you are generating the SQL that is shown in your Error Message... What you have shown so far isn't related to your problem. So Look Hard at what the error message shows and find where that SQL is being created.